# How to create multiple viewports where each viewport have different scenes?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a project, the idea of the project is simulation of gravity on different planets. I tried to find a tutorial for creating different viewports, each viewport has its own code individually so I can customize each viewport separately but I couldn't find it, most of the tutorials or examples about having different viewports of the same scene but from different angle of view.

The main vision in my mind is to split the screen into 3 parts, each part have a falling object where the acceleration of the falling object simulates the gravity acceleration on that planet.

Comment: So, where exactly are you stuck? Physics modeling, simulation, rendering…?

Comment: @Eyad: "*most of the tutorials or examples about having different viewports of the same scene but from different angle of view.*" Sure, but if you understand what that code is doing, it shouldn't be at all difficult to just change it so that it renders a different scene. The difference between what gets drawn into different viewports is pretty trivial; you just make a different draw call when you're setting up that viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have one `glViewport` call and your render you scene afterwards. To render two different scenes you just do that twice:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // this clears the whole window

glViewport(0, 0, 100, 100);
render_scene_zero();

glViewport(100, 0, 100, 100);
render_scene_one();
```

Here `render_scene_zero` and `render_scene_one` are responsible for drawing the respective scene as-if it was the only scene visible. They can draw completely different things, e.g. drawing a cube in scene zero and a sphere in scene one.